# SonarQube unit test report doesnt show Javascript files

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a maven project with modules in both Java and Javascript. 
I am not seeing the Javascript unit test files in test report in SonarQube but only Java unit test files.
    coverage_reports

In `coverage_reports` folder I have `cobertura-coverage.xml` created by Jest.
Is this `sonar.javascript.jstest.reportPaths` still used or has it been replaced by some other configuration. We are using Sonarqube 6.7 at our server.

Edit:
For others to know, I used `jest-sonar-reporter` and test script as

`"test": "cross-env CI=true  NODE_PATH=./src react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage --no-cache -u --testResultsProcessor jest-sonar-reporter"`

This created a test report xml file that I used like this

```
<sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
<sonar.testExecutionReportPaths>path/to/test-report.xml</sonar.testExecutionReportPaths>
<sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>path/to/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>
```

Comment: What does mean " I am not seeing the Javascript unit test files in test report in SonarQube"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can say `sonar.javascript.jstest.reportPaths` doesn't exist (and never did).

There are 2 things (from question I'm not sure which one you need):

1. Unit test report import (how many unit tests, which failed, which skipped etc). For that, see doc [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/TypeScript+Test+Execution+and+Coverage+Results+Import) (you will need to use `sonar.testExecutionReportPaths` property eventually).
2. Coverage report import. If you are able to produce LCOV see doc [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import). If not, you will need to convert your report in generic SonarQube format (see [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data)).

Finally, to see unit test files for JS, set correctly `sonar.tests` property (Java test files are displayed due to smart enough maven scanner)